# asp.net-core-signalr can't stay connected for more than a minute or so

Tags: azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-signalr

Just upgraded our app service from .net 4.6 to .net core. Part of that migration was to upgrade to the new .net core version of SignalR. Everything was working fine while running locally, but when it was published to an azure app service, the connection doesn't stay connected for more than a minute (usually less than 30 seconds). The error that I'm seeing in the console logs is:

Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Websocket closed with status code: 1006 ()'.

Has anyone else experienced this before? I ran across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48397181/asp-netcore-signalr-not-work-on-aws), but it has very little feedback. Not sure if it has the same root cause or not.

Comment: If there is demo code could reproduce it wil be more helpful.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this error? I got the same error, also works on localhost but not on Azure.

Comment: @n3tx Have not been able to solve this yet. Been emailing back and forth with some guys on the signalR team at Microsoft. They've been great to work with, but we haven't made much progress toward a resolution. My best guess atm is the azure load balancer has something to do with it, because both client and server say the connection was closed by the remote host. I'm about to open a support ticket with azure, so see if that route helps. If you find something keep me posted! If you have any more information than I do, feel free to post on this issue https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/2150.

Comment: Part of my problem was that I was injecting IHttpContextAccessor but I had forgot to register it in the startup.cs file. When I added it to the startup file I can keep the connection to SignalR. --> startup.cs --> services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

Comment: I don't think this was the same root issue, but thanks for commenting.

Comment: I also have the problem where the connection works on localhost, but not on Azure.

Comment: @Stephen I had the same issue, but when I opened my site in https (signalr via wss) it worked fine